# why this error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: string, flutter, dart, hive

have been in this situation for a long time now without a soluction to the error

'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>

have been making a lot of related question also hope to be assisted

Here is my class:

```
class Provider {
Provider({
required this.id,
required this.network,
required this.discount,
required this.logo,
});
final String id;
final String network;
final int discount;
final String logo;

factory Provider.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
final id = data['id'] as String;
final network = data['network'] as String;
final discount = int.parse(data['discount']);
final logo = data['logo'] as String;
return Provider(
  id: id,
  network: network,
  discount: discount,
  logo: logo,
  );
 }
}
```

and here is my functions:

```
Future<List<dynamic>> LoadData() async {
final name = await Hive.box<dynamic>('my_db');
final result = name.values.toList();
print(result);
//print result is gotten perfectly from hive box
return name.values.toList();
}
```

this my furture builder also

```
  FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                                          future: LoadData(),
                                          builder: (BuildContext context,
                                              AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                                            if (snapshot.data == null) {
                                              return const Center(
                                                child: Text('loading'),
                                              );
                                            } else {
                                              return ListView.builder(
                                                itemCount:
                                                    snapshot.data.length,
                                                itemBuilder:
                                                    (BuildContext context,
                                                        int index) {
                                                  // Decoding the string to Map
                                                   final Map<String, dynamic>
                                                      decodedData =
                                                      jsonDecode(jsonEncode(
                                                          snapshot.data[
                                                              index]));

                                                  // Mapping the Map to Provider object
                                                  final itemData =
                                                      Provider.fromJson(
                                                          decodedData);

                                                  return ListTile(
                                                    title: Row(
                                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                                          CrossAxisAlignment
                                                              .center,
                                                      children: [
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          width: 20,
                                                        ),
                                                        Row(
                                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                                              MainAxisAlignment
                                                                  .spaceEvenly,
                                                          children: [
                                                            Text(
                                                              itemData
                                                                .logo,
                                                              style:
                                                                  const TextStyle(
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .bold,
                                                                fontSize:
                                                                    20,
                                                                color: Colors
                                                                    .green,
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                            Icon(
                                                              Icons
                                                                  .more_horiz,
                                                              color: Colors
                                                                  .blue,
                                                            ),
                                                          ],
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  );
                                                },
                                              );
                                            }
                                          }),
```

hope to get help out thanks for your impact in my questions.

Comment: It would easier  to test if you could upload on github. Also can you try changing return type`Future<List<Provider>>` , you need to use adapter for hive afaik

Comment: i dont no how to go about uploading on github or how to return as `Future<List<Provider>>` am really new to flutter will be glad to get `code` example @Md. yeasin

Comment: Understandably you want an answer, but please stop duplicating your question now, ok? Please remove your previous posts, and maybe check if your have the relevant tags to atrack people with answers?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way. As recommended in [ask], it would help if you posted what have you tried to debug this error. Please read it and possibly spare a minute for the [tour]

Comment: As recommended for [mre], would it be possible for you to trim your code down to the minimum that gets the error. Dumping too much code is likely repelling volunteers from reading you through. So work on your readability, don't repost.

Comment: What line generates this error, according to a full error traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to test your code but I think the issue may come from this line:

```
final Map<String, dynamic> decodedData = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(snapshot.data[index]));
```

Try to print the value of snapshot.data[index] just above that line

```
print(snapshot.data[index]);
```

Related to the response, it will be easier to understand what is the issue and how to fix it.